# changing rate of Animation/Transition

Tags: animation, javafx-8

I'm trying to do some basic animations, but am failing at the most simple things:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100.0, 10.0);
mainPane.getChildren().add(rect); //so the rectangle is on screen
Animation anim = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(30.0),
        new KeyValue(rect.widthProperty(), 0.0, Interpolator.LINEAR)));
rect.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    if (anim.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING) {
        anim.pause();
    } else {
        anim.setRate(Math.random() * 5.0);
        anim.play();
        System.out.println(anim.getRate());
    }
});
```

The problem I am facing is that when I click the rectangle multiple times, the size will randomly jump around, instead of just changing the speed at which it drops. So for example, I let it run to about 50% size at speed ~2.5 and then stop it. When I start it up again, it will jump to a totally different size, smaller for a lower speed, bigger for a higher speed, so for example to ~20% for ~1.0 speed or ~80% for ~4.5 speed.

At first I thought animation was pre-calculated for the new speed and thus jumped to the position at which it would be, had it been played with the new speed from the beginning for the time that it was already playing before the pause, but it's bigger for a smaller speed, which doesn't really make sense then.

How do I change the speed/rate of an animation without having it jump around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your diagnosis is correct: the current value is interpolated given the current time and current rate. If you decrease the rate without changing the current time, you are then earlier in the animation. Since the animation is shrinking this has the effect of making the rectangle bigger.

The easiest way is probably just to start a new animation each time:

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.Animation.Status;
import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class VariableRateAnimation extends Application {

    private Animation anim ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane mainPane = new Pane();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100.0, 10.0);
        mainPane.getChildren().add(rect); //so the rectangle is on screen
        rect.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {

            if (anim != null && anim.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING) {
                System.out.println("Paused (" + anim.getTotalDuration().subtract(anim.getCurrentTime())+ " remaining)");
                anim.pause();
            } else {
                Duration duration = Duration.seconds(30.0 * rect.getWidth() / (100 * Math.random() * 5.0));
                System.out.println("Starting: ("+duration+ " to go)");
                double currentWidth = rect.getWidth() ;
                if (anim != null) {
                    anim.stop();
                }
                anim = new Timeline(
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(rect.widthProperty(), currentWidth, Interpolator.LINEAR)),
                        new KeyFrame(duration, new KeyValue(rect.widthProperty(), 0.0, Interpolator.LINEAR)));
                anim.play();
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(mainPane, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the old animation be properly garbage collected? Since it is only paused, it could be continued any time? As I have read, animations should be stopped when no longer needed, but using anim.stop() would also reset the play head, which is not what I want.

Comment: Hmm. The documentation says "A running `Timeline` is referenced from the FX runtime." I don't know if "paused" counts as "running", but perhaps it is better to call `stop()` to be safe. See updated code...